# MySQL to SQL Server select statement

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql

I am converting mysql sprocs to SQL Server.  I've come across a select statement in mysql that I don't quite understand what it's doing and my google-fu/so-fu has failed me.  Here is the gist of it:

```
    SELECT AccountType = dbo.functionToGetAccountType() FROM AccountLookup
```

I don't have the ability to debug the original mysql.  I do know that the function only returns a single value.

Is the mysql statement assigning a default value to 'AccountType' in the event there are no rows in the AccountLookup table?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The select statement is executing the function `dbo.functionToGetAccountType()` and aliasing the column as `AccountType`. It could be re-written as:

```
SELECT dbo.functionToGetAccountType() as AccountType
FROM AccountLookup
```